# Inverse of an Integer Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integers

I found a problem on the 
[Open Problem Garden](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/op/inverse_of_an_integer_matrix) which asks about the conditions on a rectangular, full-rank, integer matrix such that its right inverse (given by:  $A^T (AA^T)^{-1}$ ) is also an integer matrix. The rectangular matrix is constructed in the following way :

Let **D** be a square diagonal matrix (size $m \times  m$) with integer elements $\geq$ 2 along the main diagonal (in order to ensure full rank and thus existence of a right inverse)

Let **X** be an integer matrix (size $m \times  n$) with $n\geq m$.

Now, concatenate the matrices to make a new rectangular matrix **M** = [**D X**], giving it dimension $m \times  (m+n)$. I am interested in the right inverse of this matrix **M**.

I have written code to test some matrices, and I have yet to find even one integral *element*, let alone an entire matrix. I've done some algebraic analysis on a general 2x4 matrix, and intuitively it looks as though some elements will never be a non-zero integer, but it is difficult to prove. If anyone has any advice on how to proceed or any insight, that would be great.

*Edits: Clarified the characterization of the matrices in question. Renamed matrices for consistency.*

Comment: Your question is not the same as posted in OPG. There the matrix $A$ has restrictions on its form. And, also, you are posting a particular form for the right inverse. So, are you asking the question as in OPG, or are you asking the more general question you have phrased?

Comment: You are correct, I intended on asking the question which is posed in OPG - I've edited the question to reflect these conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Still, do you want to force the right inverse to be $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$?

Comment: Also, the condition $n\geq m$ does not appear in the original problem.

Comment: n $>=$ m is in the original problem. The formula for the right inverse is the only way I know to consistently find the right inverse of a given matrix. I suppose I shouldn't force it to be such, but I do not know how else I would go about finding it.

Comment: The original problem says $n\geq m$, but $n$ is not the number of columns of $M$, but the number of columns of $X$. As for the right inverse, it is not unique for a rectangular matrix, so there cannot be a formula. So, requiring the right inverse to be $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ makes the problem harder than the original.

Comment: Ah I see the issue; in rewriting the problem I had mixed up the naming of matrices M and X (which I have now fixed). I am however having a hard time thinking of how to approach this problem without restricting the inverses to that format - do you have any advice?

Comment: I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for a square 2x2 matrix with each element larger than or equal to 2:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}3 & -2\\-4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Fortunately the determinant for this matrix is equal $1$ :)

Comment: correct, by construction

Comment: -1: this doesn't answer the question, where the given matrix is not square.

Answer (score 1):

If $\begin{bmatrix} R\\ S\end{bmatrix} $ is a right inverse for $M$, we have 
$$
I=\begin{bmatrix} D&X\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R\\ S\end{bmatrix} =DR+XS. 
$$
Comparing diagonal entries, we have  for all $k$
$$\tag1
D_{kk}R_{kk}+\sum_h X_{kh}S_{hk}=1
$$
We can see the above as [Bézout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_three_or_more_integers), so a necessary condition for all entries of $R$ and $S$ to be integers is that for all $k$ the tuples $D_{kk}, X_{k1},\ldots,X_{kn}$ (i.e., the nonzero elements in each row of $M$) are coprime.

The remaining equalities are, for $k\ne j$,
$$\tag2
D_{kk}R_{kj}+\sum_hX_{kh}S_{hj}=0. 
$$
If each $S_{hj}$ is a multiple of $D_{kk}$, we can solve for $R_{kj}$: so we get a sufficient condition if $S_{hj}$ is a multiple of $\prod_{r\ne j}D_{rr}$. This requires (by $(1)$) that $D_{11},\ldots,D_{mm}$ are coprime. Thus

> A sufficient condition for $M$ to have a right-inverse with integer entries is that
>
> - for each $k$, the numbers $D_{kk}, X_{k1},\ldots,X_{kn}$ are coprime;
> - the numbers $D_{11},\ldots,D_{mm}$ are coprime.

---

To see an example of how to use this, take 
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ X=\begin{bmatrix}4&5\\6&7 \end{bmatrix}  . 
$$

We want $S_{hj}=\left(\prod_{r\ne j}D_{rr}\right)\,S_{hj}'$. So the two equalities in $(1)$ become 
$$
\begin{cases}1=2R_{11}+X_{11}\times D_{22}\times S_{11}'+X_{12}\times D_{22}\times S_{21}'\\
1=3R_{22}+X_{21}\times D_{11}\times S_{12}'+X_{22}\times D_{11}\times S_{22}'
\end{cases}
$$
That is, we need 
$$
\begin{cases} 1=2R_{11}+4\times 3\times S_{11}'+5\times 3\times S_{21}'\\
1=3R_{11}+6\times 2\times S_{12}'+ 7\times 2\times S_{22}'
\end{cases}
$$
For instance (among infinitely many possible choices)
$$
\begin{cases}
1=2(-13)+4\times 3\times 1+5\times 3\times 1\\
1=3\times 9+6\times 2\times (-1)+7\times 2\times (-1)
\end{cases}
$$
This gives us $R_{11}=-13$, $R_{22}=9$, and 
$$
S_{11}=3,\ S_{21}=3,\ S_{12}=-2,\ S_{22}=-2. 
$$
Now we can write, from $(2)$, 
$$
R_{12}=-(X_{11}S_{12}+X_{12}S_{22})/D_{11}=-(4\times (-2)+5\times (-2))/2=9,
$$
$$
R_{21}=-(X_{21}S_{11}+X_{22}S_{21})/D_{22}=-(6\times 3+7\times 3)/3=-13.
$$
So $R=\begin{bmatrix} -13&9\\ -13&9\end{bmatrix}$. Now you can check directly that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2&0&4&5\\ 0&3&6&7\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -13&9\\-13&9\\ 3&-2\\3&-2\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$

---

In general we may use that $(2)$ can be written as $$\tag3R_{kj}=-\frac{(XS)_{kj}}{D_{kk}},\ \ \ \ \ k\ne j.$$

For another example, if $D=\begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&5\end{bmatrix} $ and $M=\begin{bmatrix} 5&7\\4&5\\6&7\end{bmatrix}$ the algorithm, with the choices 
\begin{cases}
1=2(-127) + 5\times 30+ 7\times 15 \\
1=3(-43)+ 4\times 20 + 5\times 10\\
1=5\times 23+6\times (-12)+7\times (-6)
\end{cases} gives $R_{11}=-127$, $R_{22}=-43$, $R_{33}=23$, $S=\begin{bmatrix} 30&20&-12\\ 15&10&-6 \end{bmatrix}$ and then using $(3)$ 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0&5&7\\0&3&0&4&5\\0&0&5&6&7\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -127&-85&51\\ -65&-43&26\\ -57&-38&23\\ 30&20&-12\\ 15&10&-6\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Finally,  note that there are infinitely many choices for the matrix $S$ via $(1)$, so the algorithm produces infinitely many different right inverses.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a necessary condition for the inverse of a square integer matrix to also be an integer matrix as follows:

If $A$ is a square integer matrix then its determinant $\det (A)$ is an integer. Similarly if $A^{-1}$ exists and is an integer matrix then $\det (A^{-1})$ is an integer too. But $\det(A)\det(A^{-1}) = \det(AA^{-1}) = \det(I) = 1$. So you are looking for two integers whose product is 1 ... there are not many choices ...

Comment: -1: this doesn't answer the question, as the matrix in the question is not square.